# Nvidia drivers not working on Toshiba AC100

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, arm

I had ubuntu 11.10 working well on this netbook, but I decided to upgrade to the latest release. I followed official [ubuntu wiki tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100) and managed to install the system correctly.

What bugs me, is that I can't get the graphics driver to work. The suggested package located at

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-tegra/12~beta1-0ubuntu1/+build/3019146/+files/nvidia-tegra_12%7Ebeta1-0ubuntu1_armel.deb
```

doesn't work. Ubuntu software center says:

```
Unkown architecture 'armel'.
```

With no graphic drivers, the netbook is laggy (probably processor taking care of the graphics as well).

What is the problem? Is there a working package, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the arrival of 12.10 this got fixed. Toshiba is now working nicely on the [official Lubuntu 12.10 version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100).